# How do I compare objects from initial arraylist to multiple arraylists until it returns true?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
    public  boolean makeSuggestion(ArrayList<Cards> firstPlayerCards,ArrayList<Cards> secondPlayerCards){
    Iterator<Cards> p1Iterator = firstPlayerCards.iterator();
    while (p1Iterator.hasNext()) {
        Iterator<Cards> p2Iterator = secondPlayerCards.iterator();
        while(p2Iterator.hasNext()) {
            Cards p1card = p1Iterator.next();
            Cards p2card = p2Iterator.next();
            if (p1card.equals(p2card)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Here's what I have so far. I want to compare the objects of the very first arraylist(firstPlayerCards) to other arraylist's objects **until it finds an object equal to it.** Then it will return true and stop the method.

Comment: Switch `true` and `false` in your code.

Comment: `return !Collections.disjoint(firstPlayerCards, secondPlayerCards);`

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

```
public  boolean makeSuggestion(ArrayList<Cards>firstPlayerCards, ArrayList<ArrayList<Cards>> compareLists){

    //For each card in first list
    for(Cards first: firstPlayerCard){

        //For each list you wish to compare against
        for(ArrayList<Cards> secondPlayerCards: compareLists){

            //For each card in the list compare against first list
            for(Cards second: secondPlayerCards){
                if(first.equals(second)) return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This iterates through the first list of cards, and for every one of those cards it iterates through the second list and compares each object, returning true if they are equal.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't being very clear, but I wanted it to loop its iteration process through infinite arraylists(theoretically) until finds an object equal to the first list's iterated objects.

Comment: Where would you be storing this "infinate arraylists" of arraylists?

Comment: I just said "theoretically" because I thought there would be an algorithm for this or a collection of methods that could make this shorter. The max arraylists it will be comparing objects with is 5 for what I'm doing right now.

Comment: would you be comparing all arraylists with eachother? so not just one arraylist againt 5 other array lists?

Comment: I want to compare the first arraylist to 5 different arraylists but it will stop its iteration when it finds an equal object between whichever arraylist. If it goes through all 5 and has found no equal objects, it will return false.

Comment: okay so you will need to change the second parameter to the list of lists you wish to compare to, then iterate through them, i have updated the answer to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
public  boolean makeSuggestion(ArrayList<Cards> firstPlayerCards,ArrayList<Cards> secondPlayerCards){
    for(Card firstPlayerCard:firstPlayerCards){
        for(Card secondPlayerCard:secondPlayerCards){
            if(firstPlayerCard.equals(secondPlayerCard)){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```